# Issue with os.path.getmtime() (Python)

Tags: macos, python-3.x, osx-yosemite, os.path

For my program, I'm trying to make a `'commiting'` system, which saves the time edited to a file. I want another part of my program to allow you to see the total number of files modified (by comparing current dates to the saved ones). However, using `os.path.getmtime(file)`,
I always get the same number (1429051569.0). If it helps, I'm using OS X 10.10.
Any ideas?

Comment: …are you modifying the file between calls to `getmtime`?

Comment: Yes, I am - http://pastebin.com/8WfEJvkL
I call `commit()`, which saves the result of `getmtime` for each file to the HISTORY file. Then, I call `log()`, which runs `getmtime` again, and compares it to the stored values in the HISTORY file